# Runtime Error after changing file path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, runtime-error

So I have a link that once clicked opens a pdf file. I had another format and i converted it to a pdf. I then changed the path from the old pdf to the knew pdf and now whenever i try to access a page that contains this pdf link I get the Runtime Error page and `<customeErrors mode = "Off"/>` Not really sure how changing the file path affects the overall access page that has the pdf file as a link to click and open. Any insight will be appreciated.

This is the line where i added the path for the new pdf file:

```
<li class="nomove"><a href="pdfs/KVFlipBook2012Rev.pdf" target="_blank">Children w/Special Medical Needs</a></li>
```

This is my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
            <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
```

Comment: Any code will be appreciated. And btw, the error you're getting saying that you won't get the real error unless you will add the node to the `web.config` file.

Comment: @gdoron added more code including my web.config